# Do we have a thread library that is compatible with Turbo C?

Tags: c, multithreading, turbo-c

Currently I am developing a program for academic purpose. We use Turbo C because we are requesting for interrupt directly with the hardware.

We can do anything for our project, and I've already chosen a topic. The thing is I think I really need 2 threads in my program. Are there any thread libraries that are compatible with Turbo C in this case?

Comment: Is this DOS?  (Real-mode DOS, not a DOS box under Windows.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We use Turbo C because we are
>   requesting for interrupt directly with
>   the hardware

Many Windows programs interact directly with the hardware without being written in a DOS environment in Turbo C. Take a look at the [WDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_DDK) for more information about this.

Comment: I understand that there are many more tools out there that allow us to request for interrupt, however, academically, with respect to the given assignment, using Turbo C is a must.

Comment: Fair enough. ------ If it's pure DOS then, I think you can't have threads - it's a strictly single-process/thread OS. You can only simulate them with the hardware interrupt or something